# Openpyxl 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upper'

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to load an existing workbook using Openpyxl, however, when I execute the code, I get the error:

```
>>> wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Stats.xlsx')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Stats.xlsx')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 233, in load_workbook
    parser.parse()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 104, in parse
    dispatcher[tag_name](element)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 241, in parse_row_dimensions
    self.parse_cell(cell)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 180, in parse_cell
    row, column = coordinate_to_tuple(coordinate)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\__init__.py", line 162, in coordinate_to_tuple
    col, row = coordinate_from_string(coordinate)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\__init__.py", line 39, in coordinate_from_string
    match = COORD_RE.match(coord_string.upper())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

Comment: Please share the full traceback.

Comment: I just shared the Traceback

Comment: Can you post your OpenPyXl version?

To do so, post the result of the following code snippet:
`import openpyxl; openpyxl.__version__`

Comment: Sure the version I am using is 2.3.0

Comment: This is likely a bug in the library. So please try the [latest version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl), 2.3.2 at the time of this writing. If the error doesn't go a away you'll need to file [an issue](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues), but it'd be helpful having a minimal file that triggers the issue.

Comment: If this is a file where the coordinates are not written in the individual cells then openpyxl won't be able to read it. Please upgrade to the most recent release and submit a bug report with a sample file.